Getting 404 when passing blank parameter in CodeIgniter 4
I have a route that accept a parameter and shows the output based on it, and if the parameter is null or not exists then it showing a full list of movie.
I've already define the default value of the parameter but it still throwing a 404 error on me
Controller :
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;


class APIController extends BaseController
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    public function index($genre = null)
    {

        if ($genre != null) {
            echo "the genre is $genre";
            //Do filtering genre movie here 

        } else {
            $film = [
                [
                    "judul" => 'Terowongan Casablanca',
                    "genre" => 'horor'
                ],
                [
                    "judul" => 'Lorem ipsum',
                    'genre' => 'comedy'
                ],
                [
                    "judul" => 'Shadowbringer',
                    "genre" => 'action'
                ]
            ];
            $filmJson = json_encode($film);
            return $this->respond($film, 200);
        }
    }
}

Router:
<?php

use CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection;

/**
 * @var RouteCollection $routes
 */
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/daftar-film/(:any)', 'ApiController::index/$1');
$routes->get('/daftar-film/(.+)', 'ApiController::index/$1');


Is the class name case sensitive ? In Router: try changing ApiController -> APIController

Didn't realize that I write the class in lower case , but yea I tried to write APIController still no luck , it shown there is Can't find a route for 'get: daftar-film/'.

well it can be solved by creating the new get route with no slug and calling the index class that shows all of the movies, but it kinda defeat the purposes of the default value of the slug,
